# Sort a list based on URL parameter (or sort nested domain model in query)

Tags: list, grails, grails-2.0

I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I'm really stuck on this one.

I have a domain model that connects to entities `Foo` and `Bar` in a many-to-many-relationship. Now when I want to list all Foos to a certain Bar, I do the query and get a lot of `FooBar` objects. I iterate through these objects and add all `Foo`s to a list.

Like so:

```
def fooBarRelations = FooBar.findAllByBar bar
def fooList = []
fooBarRelations.each { fooList.add it.foo }
```

How can I sort the `fooList` based upon the parameters a `g:sortableColumn` adds to the url namely `sort` (the field to sort) and `order`.

I know you can pass the parameters to the query directly but I think this is not possible in my case?

So how can I either

1. Make one query without list iterating so I can pass in the sorting parameters **OR**
2. Sort my custom list based upon the sorting parameters?

#### Addition 1 (03/25/2012)

If I could to this ...

```
def fooBarRelations = FooBar.findAllByBar bar, [sort: 'foo.' + params.sort, order: params.order]
```

... the problem would be solved. But passing this to the query does not have any effect on the output. Is there any way I can sort a query by a sub-property?

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't sort within the query itself. Then you need a list of lists.

```
List<List<Fields>> mylist;// where List<Fields> is a lists of the fields.
```

Then use a Comparator to sort your List> by the desired filed. Say your desired field is at index 3:

```
 new Compare(List<Fields> L1, List<Fields> L2){
     if(L1.get(3)>L2.get(3))
          return -1;//etc.
```

UPATE BASED ON COMMENT:

say your entity is as follows

```
public class Entity{
    String name, address, school;
    Integer bankaccount;
    //etc...
}
```

Then

```
public class WhereISort{
    List<Entity> myList;
    String mysorter;//mysorter can be declared here as static final
    public WhereISort(){//maybe pass list in here or whatever
    }

    public Response myWebService(params..., String sorter){
       mysorter=sorter;//mysorter can be declared here as static final
       Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Entity e1, Entity e2) {
            if(mysorter.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
               return e1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(e1.getName());
            }else if(mysorter.equalsIgnoreCase("bankaccount")){
                //your code here, etc.
            }
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Of course, the main point is using "mysorter" and the inner class "Comparator" to sort

Comment: That's not what I want. I have a lot of entities that are not directly in a list, but in a list of another object which holds them (among other things). So I just copy them to a different list. And I need to sort this list after a certain property of the domain model which I get in the URL (like `?sort=name`)